# Automating the Trading Web Application using Selenium

Tags: java, c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Our application is **'Online Trading Platform'**.

Now we need to implement automation for this application.

Is it possible to automate a trading platform which gets live streaming data.

Application is developed based on C#.Net.

If possible, how can we do it using Selenium.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. However *how* to do it is way to broad.

Comment: hi guy, way to broad means. Is it very complex to automate trading platform which gets streaming data from stock exchange

Comment: To broad means we can't give you simple answer how to do it. We don't know the platform, how it is working or what should be tested in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As long as your application runs on Web Browser.

According to [Seleniumhq.org](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

> > **What is Selenium?**
>
> - Selenium automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power    is entirely up to you. Primarily, it is for automating web
>     applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to
>     just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!)
>     also be automated as well.

Comment: thanks for response. Application is running in web browser only but my problem is the data will changing continuously during trading hours. So how can I proceed with testing if data is changing. Please suggest.

Comment: What exactly you need do? Capture data when ever it got updated?

Comment: Yes, need to capture immediately. Eg., while validating 'Trade' we will calculate price range based on LastDone. So when Last price updated price range which we are calculating also need to be updated and validate.

Answer (score 0):

Like any modern application, the data, controls bound to be changed and hence captured. You may need to define some variable for example LastPrice, CurrPrice and once they are stored you can do the calculations and execute next steps.

Comment: @Asad Hussain, thanks for your reply. Can store and calculate the values but the problem is need to capture for every update and calculate. Please suggest a way to capture the values everytime.